# WSGIDaemonProcess, Etc. Causing Connection Timeout in Debian 9

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I was previously running `Debian 8` and hosting my `Django` app using the following setup:

- *Django 1.11*
- *mod-wsgi 4.5*
- *apache 2.4*
- *mysql*

Now that I have updated to `Debian 9`, and using `mariaDB`, I am having an issue using the following settings in my `apache2.conf` file:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/root/.virtualenvs/user/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so"
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/web/user.com/project/project/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess user.com socket-user=user group=user processes=2 threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup user.com
WSGIPythonHome "/root/.virtualenvs/user" <-- outside of virtual host
```

I took each line out to see which was causing the issue, with `LoadModule wsgi_module "/root/.virtualenvs/user/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so"` being the only one that was allowed to be in there and not cause the site to hang.

By taking out all of those lines, my site works (albeit, without static files) and is not running in Daemon mode... My error logs show nothing except the following:

```
2017/12/05 08:59:15 [error] 446#446: *80 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: X.X.X.X, server: website.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://X.X.X.X:8080/", host: "website.com"
2017/12/05 09:00:00 [error] 446#446: *80 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: X.X.X.X, server: website.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://X.X.X.X:8080/", host: "website.com"
```

How do I fix this??

Comment: The ``/root`` directory is normally only readable by ``root`` user, not arbitrary users. So wouldn't be able to read the virtual environment. Why do you have the virtual environment under ``/root``?

Comment: Aahhhh, this might just be my fudge up. Since reinstalling Debian, I haven't yet moved my virtual environment folder... Let me fix that when I get home and confirm it does work and nothing else is goofed up! @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton , that has solved my issue. I can't thank you enough for all the help through this process that I've overcomplicated!